# vue.js/webpack: How to properly transpile ES6/ES7?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, async-await, vue.js, babeljs

I set up my project with the [full webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).
How do I set it up to use ES7 features like async functions? I read about using babel plugins and tried the following:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            plugins: [require("babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator")]
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding: This won't transpile the async function in `.vue` files because it only looks for the `.js` files.
Somehow it works for these - but then it gives me arrow functions which don't work in IE again.

To wrap it up: How can I set up transpiling to use ES6 and ES7 features?

Comment: Try to add `stage-3` to presets (change `"stage2"` to `["stage-2", "stage-3"]`), install via `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-3`.

Comment: For vue loader loaders are supposed to be specified inside its options: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/advanced.html . I guess that babel loader should pick up .babelrc, so Babel config can be specified there.

Comment: @wostex: Where do I have to change this? There's no literal in my whole project specifying "stage-2" or similar...

Comment: @estus: It's strange, the docs don't seem to be in line with the boilerplate - so confusing.

Comment: @Sandrooco my comment was about `babel.rc` - all editions should go there.

Comment: @wostex: My project (from the boilerplate) doesn't have any babel.rc :s

Comment: Your problem seems to be that `async`/`await` is an ES8 feature.

Comment: @Bergi Any idea on how to use the babel plugins with the webpack boilerplate?

Comment: @Sandrooco I've installed `vue init webpack project-name` - there's `babel.rc` inside, doublecheck it.

Comment: In which folder should it be? I'm sure there isn't any! Any chance that I screwed up the setup?

Comment: OK @wostex it worked by adding a `.babelrc` (there was really none!) and the `stage-3` thing. :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of our discussion:

1) the babel config `.babelrc` should be edited to handle `async-await`, for example add `stage-3` preset:

```
"presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-2", 
    "stage-3"
  ],
```

2) install this preset

npm: `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-3`

yarn: `yarn add -D babel-preset-stage-3`

Answer (score 0):

FYI, just incase someone else stumbled upon it and was not able to use async/await with Vuejs projects (like me), here is what I did to get it working -

In order to use *await/async* you will need to install a couple of Babel dependencies. This works with Vuejs project -

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-regenerator
```

Once installed, you will need to modify your **.babelrc** file to use the plugin as follows -

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-regenerator"]
}
```

and also your **webpack.config.js** file to use the regenerator as follows -

```
require("babel-polyfill");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./app.js"]
};
```

*Make the necessary changes according to your project structure and filename etc.*

Posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734082/2074938