# Loading spinner when making Axios request

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a simple button in a form and I would like to show a spinner when I make Axios request. Here's my button with spinner (from loading.io).

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" class="form-inline">
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-5" id="loading" :disabled="loading">
    <div class="lds-ring" v-if="loading"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

There is a spinner which I show conditionally when `loading` is `true`.

I have defined `onSubmit` method but where I dispatch an action and change `loading` to `true` before the request and to `false` when the request is complete but it doesn't work. Could you explain me why?

#### onSubmit()

```
onSubmit () {
        const formData = {
          start_address: this.start_address,
          destination_address: this.destination_address,
          price_cents: this.price_cents,
          date: this.date
        }
        this.loading = true
        this.$store.dispatch('createRide', formData)
        this.loading = false
      }
```

#### create_ride

```
createRide({ commit }, ride){
    axios.post('/api/trips', ride)
      .then(response => {
        commit('addRide', response.data)
      })
      .then(response => {
        commit('showSuccessAlert')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        commit('showErrorAlert')
      })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for the promise to resolve when dispatching the api call, as you have it written the loading property is immediately being set to false. Try changing the method to:

```
async onSubmit () {
    const formData = {
      start_address: this.start_address,
      destination_address: this.destination_address,
      price_cents: this.price_cents,
      date: this.date
    }
    this.loading = true

    // using await
    await this.$store.dispatch('createRide', formData)
    this.loading = false

    // or without await
    this.$store.dispatch('createRide', formData).then(() => {
      this.loading = false
    })
  }
```

The vuex store action should be updated as well:

```
async createRide({ commit }, ride){
  await axios.post('/api/trips', ride)
    .then(response => {
      commit('addRide', response.data)
    })
    .then(response => {
      commit('showSuccessAlert')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      commit('showErrorAlert')
    })
})
```

Comment: I needed to install 2 plugins: "babel-polyfill" and "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need to transpile the async/await syntax using webpack and babel or equivalent. Vue cli 3 provides this out of the box. What are you using in your build process?

Comment: Try with await instead of returning from the vuex action.

Comment: I have followed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389267/using-async-await-with-webpack-simple-configuration-throwing-error-regeneratorr and configured webpack.conf.js and .babelrc aoccrdingly

Comment: I do it like that: `await this.$store.dispatch('createRide', formData)` but no luck still

Comment: Change the vuex action: `await axios.post('/api/trips', ride)`

Comment: I have tried both with `await` and without with `.then` and no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184804/discussion-between-jedi-and-digitaldrifter).

Comment: Would you explain to me how it all works, please? I am pretty new to this.

Comment: There are a lot of newer JavaScript features that have limited or no support across the range of browsers and versions out there in the wild, so to ensure functionality for the highest percentage possible, the code is transpiled, or converted so to speak, to [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript). Promises, async/await are a common case. If you want a good, in-depth read I suggest this [site](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-promises-in-depth); well written articles with practical examples. Hope this helps!