# Using the async/await pattern in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I want to use the async/await pattern with my new Vue.js project. However, after my first try, it threw an error:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Test</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(value, name) in pickingList">
                <td>{{value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        s
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Test',
        data() {
            return {
                pickingList: null,
                pickingZone: '1006'
            }
        },
        async created() {
            await this.getPickingList();
        },
        methods: {
            async getPickingList() {
                this.pickingZone = await this.$http.get("Picking/PickingZoneLists/" + this.pickingZone);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This throws the folloring error:

> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:629 [Vue warn]:
>   Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not
>   defined"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/views/Test.vue
>           at src/containers/TheContainer.vue
>             at src/App.vue
>               warn @ webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:629
>   webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:1896
>   ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
>       at VueComponent.created (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:25)
>       at invokeWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:1862)
>       at callHook (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:4216)
>       at VueComponent.Vue._init (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:5001)
>       at new VueComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:5147)
>       at createComponentInstanceForVnode (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3289)
>       at init (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3120)
>       at merged (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3307)
>       at createComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:5973)
>       at createElm (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:5920)

After some research, I found a solution which suggested to install the following two babel plugins:

- @babel/polyfill
- @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator

I've installed them via npm and added them to my babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env']
    ],
    plugins: [
        ['@babel/polyfill'],
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator']
    ]
}
```

After that, my page crashes immediately with an unspecific error page full of SocketExceptions and HttpRequestExceptions:

> Failed to proxy the request to http://localhost:8081/mypage, because
>   the request to the proxy target failed. Check that the proxy target
>   server is running and accepting requests to http://localhost:8081/.
>   The underlying exception message was 'Es konnte keine Verbindung
>   hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung
>   verweigerte.'.Check the InnerException for more details.

Were the two babel plugins even the right track? If yes, how can I fix the problem?

I also found [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389267/using-async-await-with-webpack-simple-configuration-throwing-error-regeneratorr), but I don't have a webpack config file. Here's my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    //Necessary to run npm link https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-symlinks
    resolve: {
       symlinks: false
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template",
  "version": "3.0.0-beta.3",
  "description": "Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template",
  "author": {
    "name": "CoreUI",
    "url": "https://coreui.io",
    "github": "https://github.com/coreui",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/core_ui"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "CoreUI Team",
      "url": "https://github.com/orgs/coreui/people"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "http://coreui.io",
  "copyright": "Copyright 2019 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "clearCache": "jest --clearCache",
    "release": "npm-run-all clearCache lint build test:unit test:e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "@coreui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@coreui/utils": "^1.0.0",
    "@coreui/vue": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "@coreui/vue-chartjs": "^1.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "chromedriver": "^79.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.4.8",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 9"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.10.x",
    "npm": ">= 5.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `created()` doesn't need to be async btw, if there's nothing in the created lifecycle hook that is awating `this.getPickingList()`

Comment: How does the proxy error relate to your webpack config? *Is* there something running on port 8081?

Comment: Info: Webpack is configured with default values if no webpack config (or no `configureWebpack` section in vue.config.js) is present - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html

Comment: @Tanner I've added my vue.config.js

Comment: @Terry Thank you for your suggestion. I've removed it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope. The error goes away as soon as I comment out the two plugin imports from my babel.config.js and restart the project.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Could you also add your `package.json`?

Comment: What is `this.$http`?  That's not a Vue thing.  Use `axios` or `fetch`.

Comment: @Dan That's from the VueAxios plugin. It's just a wrapper that adds axios to the Vue object.

Comment: @Tanner Thank you. I've edited my question.

Comment: And what happens if you use raw axios instead?  And do you need a `/` before the `Picking/PickingZoneLists/` path?  There's nothing wrong the code otherwise.

Comment: @Dan Even if I comment out that line completely, it still doesn't start up properly and throws the weird http proxy errors.

Comment: Then it's probably best now to start a fresh project, ensure that it works by default, then add bits until you reproduce the error.  It sounds like a plugin problem.

Comment: @Dan My problem is, that I don't even know, if I chose the right plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a relatively recent Medium post on this subject. `@babel/polyfill` is deprecated. You'll need to install `@babel/runtime` and `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`, then make some changes to your babel.config.js:

```
npm i -D @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
npm i @babel/runtime
```

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        // "absoluteRuntime": false,
        "corejs": false,
        // "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true,
        // "useESModules": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Source Article: https://medium.com/@kishan020696/react-16-with-webpack-4-and-babel-7-part-2-edb34d78f695

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the solution.