# TypeError: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack, typeerror, uglifyjs, webpack-cli

I'm experiencing a `TypeError` and am unsure how to resolve it. I look forward to any help you can provide.  The following is the terminal output from `yarn run build`:

```
BUILD_DIR /Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/build
SRC_DIR /Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/src
[webpack-cli] TypeError: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin is not a constructor
    at module.exports (/Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/webpack.config.js:118:7)
    at WebpackCLI.loadConfig (/Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1589:33)
    at async WebpackCLI.resolveConfig (/Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1677:38)
    at async WebpackCLI.createCompiler (/Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:2085:22)
    at async WebpackCLI.runWebpack (/Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:2213:20)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:850:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/blakelucey/Desktop/fsd-next/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1516:13)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

This is the `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
// const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].fonts.css');
const extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].styles.css');
// const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

console.log('BUILD_DIR', BUILD_DIR);
console.log('SRC_DIR', SRC_DIR);

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  return {
    entry: {
      index: [SRC_DIR + '/index.tsx']
    },
    output: {
      path: BUILD_DIR,
      filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', 'scss']
    },
    // watch: true,
    devtool: env.prod ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
      //   port: 9001,
      compress: true,
      hot: true,
      open: true
    },
    // optimization: {
    //   minimizer: [
    //     new UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true})
    //   ]
    // },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: ['react', 'env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(scss)$/,
          use: ['css-hot-loader'].concat(extractSCSS.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: { alias: { '../img': '../public/img' } }
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
              }
            ]
          }))
          // loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: extractCSS.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: 'css-loader'
          })
          // loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          use: [
            {
              // loader: 'url-loader'
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: './img/[name].[hash].[ext]'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: './fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
          }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ sourceMap: true }),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      extractCSS,
      extractSCSS,
      // new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      //   // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      //   // both options are optional
      //   filename: "[name].css",
      //   chunkFilename: "[id].css"
      // }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        {
          inject: true,
          template: './public/index.html'
        }
      ),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './public/img', to: 'img' }
      ],
        { copyUnmodified: false }
      ),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './public/robot.txt', to: 'robot.txt' }
      ],
        { copyUnmodified: false }
      )
    ]
  }
};
```

I think I need to remove my comments here:

```
// const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
```

and here:

```
// optimization: {
    //   minimizer: [
    //     new UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true})
    //   ]
    // },
```

But I'm not sure.  I look forward to and appreciate any input you can contribute, thank you.

Answer (score 14):

As you may notice that the plugin `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` is being deprecated and in the [`terser-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) comes in as replacement. So `UglifyJsPlugin` plugin is likely unavailable in `webpack.optimize`. So here is a possible way to fix your issue:

- Just remove the following line in your config file:

```js
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ sourceMap: true })
// Remove this ^
```

- and add the plugin to `optimizer`:

```js
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  // ...
};
```

Regarding `NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor`, it's also be deprecated you can find out [here](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#update-outdated-options) if you're using `webpack 5`. Basically you can remove that plugin and replace it with optimization option:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  // NamedModulesPlugin → optimization.moduleIds: 'named'
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'named',
  },
};
```

Comment: This did take care of the error above, however, I am getting a new error:  `webpack-cli] TypeError: webpack.NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor`.  Do you have any suggestions on how I can remedy this?  Thanks.

Comment: Just updated the answer regarding to your issue

Answer (score 0):

I searched the internet and came across issues like the following but could not solve my project problem

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389267/using-async-await-with-webpack-simple-configuration-throwing-error-regeneratorr][1]

Comment: Please don't post a comment as a answer, @reza.