# Webpack Error when `yarn run build` ran in my docker build

Tags: javascript, docker, webpack, dockerfile, modulenotfounderror

**This is the error that occurred upon running my build:**

```
WARNING in configuration
#12 0.535 The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
#12 0.535 Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
#12 0.535 You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
#12 0.535 
#12 0.535 ERROR in main
#12 0.535 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/src'
#12 0.535 resolve './src' in '/src'
#12 0.535   using description file: /src/package.json (relative path: .)
#12 0.535     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
#12 0.535     using description file: /src/package.json (relative path: ./src)
#12 0.535       no extension
#12 0.535         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
#12 0.535         /src/src doesn't exist
#12 0.535       .js
#12 0.535         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
#12 0.535         /src/src.js doesn't exist
#12 0.535       .json
#12 0.535         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
#12 0.535         /src/src.json doesn't exist
#12 0.535       .wasm
#12 0.535         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
#12 0.535         /src/src.wasm doesn't exist
#12 0.535       as directory
#12 0.535         /src/src doesn't exist
```

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12.10

 
WORKDIR /src

COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

#Note the dependency install
RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get -y install libcairo2-dev \
 libpango1.0-dev \
 libjpeg-dev \
 libgif-dev \
 librsvg2-dev

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run build

EXPOSE 3000

COPY . . 

CMD ["node", "./server"]
```

**You can find a copy of my webpack.config.js [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69468568/13844056).**

I'm not sure if my webpack configuration is correct or if the source of the error lies in my Dockerfile.  I look forward to your insight. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would check what's the value of this variable `const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');`, it's the only place I see you do something with the `src` directory and the error complains about yarn looking for `/src/src` when it seems like it should be just `/src`

Comment: @arieljuod Per my webpack.config.js: 
`const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

console.log('BUILD_DIR', BUILD_DIR);
console.log('SRC_DIR', SRC_DIR);

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  return {
    entry: {
      index: [SRC_DIR + '/index.tsx']`

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: You need to `COPY` your application code into the image before you `RUN yarn build`.  Right now that `COPY` is at the end of the Dockerfile, and when you try to build the image, its source code isn't there yet, only the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files.

Comment: @DavidMaze After moving COPY and changing CMD to the correct syntax I’m getting the following error: ‘[webpack-cli] TypeError: webpackNamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor at module.exports (src/webpack.config.js:122:7)’.