# when I use the word async in webpack-3 the function not work

Tags: javascript, async-await, webpack-3

I was using async: false in ajax. I want to have the equivalent of this command in fetch. Apparently using async helps. But when I use the word async in the webpack, it does not work.
i use webbpack 3.8.1 and in webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
  
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('allstyles_for_store_details_naghashi.css'/*'allstyles_for_store_details.css'*//*'allstyles.css'*/);
 
module.exports = { 
    entry: {
         'main': './wwwroot/source/app_for_store_details_naghashi.js' ,
     },
       
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle_for_store_details_naghashi.js' ,
        publicPath: 'dist/', 
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), 
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/, use: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader?minimize'])
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader', options: {
                        presets:
                            ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },           
        ]
    } 
};
```

in my file :

```
async function f12() {
    alert('13579-1122');  
}
f12();
```

It does not work when I use the word async.
(I want the program to wait for the fetch command to complete when the fetch command is running. I was using async: false in ajax)

Comment: Why is that function `async`? Also, you _don't_ want to use `async` (`async: false`) but you also _do_ want to use it? Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I want the program to wait for the fetch command to complete when the fetch command is running. I was using async: false in ajax. Please help me how to do this in fetch. I'm sorry I did not ask my questions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a function that just `fetches` the data, and call that function from an async function that `awaits` the response (JSON, presumably), parses it, and then you can do what you want with it.

A bit like this:

```js
function getData(url) {
  return fetch(url);
}

async function main() {
  try {
    const response = await getData('https://example.com');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

main();
```

Additional documentation

- [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)
- [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: I want to know how to use it in webpack (in the file app_for_store_details_naghashi.js which I specified in the entry section inside webpack.config.js, it will not work if I use async)

Comment: All modern browsers understand async/await. This doesn't sound like a webpack question. It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I searched the internet and came across posts like the following, but I could not fix my project problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389267/using-async-await-with-webpack-simple-configuration-throwing-error-regeneratorr